# VBScript Function Name Maximum Length

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I'm wondering what the maximum allowed length of a function name in Classic ASP (VBScript) is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is 255, but you should not abuse it :)

From the MSDN reference for [`Function`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x7hbf8fa%28VS.85%29.aspx):

> *name*
>   Name of the Function; follows standard variable naming conventions.

And from the MSDN reference for [Variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t7zd6etz%28VS.85%29.aspx):

> [...] A variable name:
>
> - Must begin with an alphabetic character.
> - Cannot contain an embedded period.
> - Must not exceed 255 characters.
> - Must be unique in the scope in which it is declared.

Answer (score 5):

The following fails with identifier too long @ 256 characters

```
for i = 1 to 1024
    execute "function " & string (i, "X") & ": end function"
    WScript.echo i
next
```